# i am storing an array in sessionstorage and retrieving through sessionstorage. I am getting the data but i am unable to repeat the array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-storage

```
var x=[
{
"xyz":1,
"abc":"Dashboard",
"def":0,
},
{
"xyz":2,
"abc":"Facility",
"def":0
}]
```

this is the original data.Then I am storing the data using session storage like below---

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem("userItems", JSON.stringify(x));
```

Then i am retrieving data using sessionstorage---

```
$window.sessionStorage.getItem("userItems")
```

i am getting the data correctly--

```
 [{
"xyz":1,
"abc":"Dashboard",
"def":0,
},
{
"xyz":2,
"abc":"Facility",
"def":0
}]
```

but i am unable to repeat the data and displaying data.

Comment: i got the answer. I have just parsed the data after getting from session storage.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap it up into a JSON.parse() :

```
JSON.parse($window.sessionStorage.getItem("userItems"));
```